# Cycle through only applications in current Desktop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

Im using Macbook M1 pro 14. with MacOS 12.4

I would like to CMD + TAB to show only application from visible screen/Desktop.
But CMD + TAB cycles through all application from various Desktop screens

For e.g. I'm currently at Desktop3 which has only Firefox, Slack open.
But when I press CMD + TAB it shows applications from other Desktops as well.

Also, Im using Logitech MK850 keyboard

Comment: Can't be done natively; but if you've only got one app open on a Space, there would be nothing to swap to…

Comment: @Tetsujin I meant just the apps from current desktop, updated

Comment: OK - still can't be done natively. I just put sets of apps fully visible in different Spaces & swap between Spaces instead.

Comment: This app does what I want, but looks like its PAID ! https://manytricks.com/witch/

Comment: Instead of ⌘+⇥ you can use ⌃+↑ (or three fingers swipe up) to activate Mission Control and have overview of apps in particular space.

Comment: I guess you'll have to decide whether this problem is more annoying than the $14 for Witch.